# Nurikolor (Level 2)

Tags: grid-deduction

Previous level: [Nurikolor (Level 1)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102774/nurikolor-level-1)
Next level: [Nurikolor (Level 3)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102805/nurikolor-level-3)

Level 2 of Nurikolor is now here. As a recap, here are the rules, but changed "X" to colors.

- There are colored numbers on the grid, which indicate the number of tiles the group of its color holds.
- There are tiles with 1 color, which indicate the color of the tile.
- There are tiles with 2 or more colors, which indicate intersections of colors. All intersections are shown, and these are the only intersections.
- Grey tiles are not part of any group; they just serve as barriers.
- The goal is to have every non-grey tile covered by a type of color.
- 2 by 2 non-grey squares of the same color are illegal.
- In future levels, there will be multiple numbers of the same color. Their groups must never intersect or be adjacent to each other at any point.
  [image: Puzzle 2]

Colorblind version:

```
--- --- -oy -ry -y9 --- ---
--- -r6 -ro --- --- xxx -l7
--- --- o10 --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- -p- --- -lg ---
--- -p6 --- --- -c- --- ---
-p- --- --- -c- -c7 -lg ---
--- --- xxx --- --- --- -g8

r = red, o = orange, y = yellow, l = lime, g = green, c = cyan, p = purple, xxx = gray
```

Comment: Could you check the area around blue 7 and dark green 8? I'm not getting a unique solution, because there are 2 ways to fill that area.

Comment: Oh. My god. Will fix :3

Comment: Looks like an interesting puzzle. But please note that we have colorblind solvers, and even though I'm not colorblind, I had initial difficulty distinguishing between the yellow and light green. [This post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89321/4-times-4-colorful-ravens-progressive-matrices) gives a good example of how setters usually provide a more accessible experience.

Comment: Colorblind version added :)

Comment: This still does not have a unique solution.  rot13: Bs gur frpbaq pryy va gur svefg ebj naq gur svefg pryyf va gur frpbaq naq guveq ebjf, rknpgyl bar vf erq ohg vg qbrfa'g znggre juvpu bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> We can start off by looking at the right side of the grid. The light green '7' must be connected to the intersection in R6C6. Hence, the four square from R3C7 to R6C7 must all be light green. Doing so allows us to fill in the colours for yellow and dark green using connectivity logic. 
>  [image: Nurikolor_1]

> Next, we focus on the cell R7C1. If this cell was purple, then there would be more than 6 cells to connect to the purple cell in R4C4. Therefore, the R7C1 cell must be blue. To connect it to the '7', we get 
>  [image: Nurikolor_2]

> Next, the cell in R5C4 must be purple as it would lead to a disconnection of either the purple or orange island. We can thus complete the purple '6' clue.
>  [image: Nurikolor_3]

> We then focus on the two cells, R4C2 and R4C3. Both of these cells must be orange. If it was red instead, it would cut off the orange 10. Since these two cells are orange, the cell R3C3 must be red to prevent a 2 x 2 orange island group. Using connectivity logic to finish up, we get 
>  [image: Nurikolor_final]

Comment: Nice job! There may be more levels coming up...