# Nurikolor (Level 4)

Tags: grid-deduction

Previous Level: [Nurikolor (Level 3)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102805/nurikolor-level-3) 
Next Level: [Massive NuriKolor (Level 5) (Red-Fury)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102820/massive-nurikolor-level-5-red-fury)

Level 4 introduces a 9x9 grid, but we still have 8 colors to work with.

- There are colored numbers on the grid, which indicate the number of tiles the group of its color holds.
- There are tiles with 1 color, which indicate the color of the tile.
- There are tiles with 2 or more colors, which indicate intersections of colors. All intersections are shown, and these are the only intersections.
- Grey tiles are not part of any group; they just serve as barriers.
- The goal is to have every non-grey tile covered by a type of color.
- 2 by 2 non-grey squares of the same color are illegal.
- In future levels, there will be multiple numbers of the same color. Their groups must never intersect or be orthogonally adjacent to each other.
- There will be colored lines in certain places. The same-color group may not cross through the colored lines, although they must border the line.

[image]

Colorblind version:

```
-p- --- --- xxx xxx --- --- --- -c8
--- --- xxx --- --- -gc --- --- ---
--- --- xxx --- --- --- xxx xxx -g9
--- -bp --- -g- -l9 -lc --- --- xxx
xxx --- -p8 --- xxx -co -o9 --- xxx
xxx -b9 --- --- --- -oy --- -yl ---
-r7 xxx xxx y12 --- --- xxx --- ---
--- --- --- -ro --- --- xxx --- ---
--- -r- --- --- xxx xxx -y- --- ---

R5C6 cyan, down

r = red, o = orange, y = yellow, l = lime, g = green, c = cyan, b = blue, p = purple, xxx = gray
```

Comment: Twice everyday sounds a little too much, and might degrade the quality of puzzles. I already see the "level 4" is actually easier than level 3, as I could solve most (if not all) parts by just looking at it for a minute.

Comment: I'm not sure this genre leads to very much interesting logic. Maybe try writing puzzles focused on particular deductions, rather than using lots of elements? You seem to be adding more and more things, which indicates to me that the base ruleset isn't very useful -- it doesn't seem like the new elements have led to particularly novel logic. As Bubbler said, you can still figure out a lot just by looking at the image for a brief second.

Comment: If you want to, I can delete all of these puzzles, and delete my account too if you want :3

Comment: Just saying if you want to, then go for it

Comment: I think the puzzle is still unsolvable because completing all the numbered regions colors 44 tiles but there are 46 blank tiles, making 2 non-gray cells blank no matter what.

Comment: The puzzle is still unsolvable - two cells will be empty. (Also, I never told you to delete everything? I was giving suggestions for how to improve your logic puzzles.)

Comment: You can fix it with minimum bother by (i) upping the indigo by 1 and either the violet or dark green by 1, or (ii) upping the indigo, violet or dark green by 2 . You can also do away with the blue line now that it does not have the numeric capacity to cross it anyway.

Comment: You know... it's a bit tiring, but I'll do it anyways.

Answer (score 3):

This puzzle is unsolvable.

> [image]
>  Because of the blue line, the square above the marked orange-yellow cell must be blue. But then the orange 9 and the yellow 12 cannot both fit through the marked cell -- but both of them need to do so to get to the other side of it.

Comment: Noticed :3 Will fix

Answer (score 1):

The puzzle is still unsolvable.

> [image]

> If you look at the picture the puzzle is actually solved with all the colours, but it is not solved due to those empty question-marked squares. Had they been grey-squares this puzzle would get solved. Make sure you do the correction and I shall show you my reasoning !

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but if you are intending to continue this with increasingly difficult puzzles, consider removing as much redundant information as possible. For example: most colors are redundant in this puzzle. I believe the slightly altered version below is also uniquely solvable, and more interesting:
[image]

(I assume the meaning of the numbers is clear)
(note: I do believe this type of puzzle has some potential)

Note: Stiv was not entirely correct upping indigo and violet allows 3 solutions, so your puzzle is not uniquely solvable

Comment: Good spot on my error in the comment on the main post (which was made fairly quickly) - hadn't twigged that the other end of the chain would then end up having multiple solutions.

Comment: ...hm. I think you have a point.