# Massive NuriKolor (Level 5) (Red-Fury)

Tags: grid-deduction

Previous Level: [Nurikolor (Level 4)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102810/nurikolor-level-4) 
Next Level: [Tapa-Nurikolor (Level 6)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/103847/tapa-nurikolor-level-6)

Level 5 introduces a 11x12 grid, and this time we have 9 colors. (Colours used here are **Red, Blue, Green, Ivory, Brown, Orange, Purple, Yellow, Lime**)

- There are colored numbers on the grid, which indicate the number of
  tiles the group of its color holds.
- There are tiles with 1 color,    which indicate the color of the tile.
- There are tiles with 2 or more    colors, which indicate intersections of colors. All intersections are    shown, and these
  are the only intersections.
- Grey tiles are not part    of any group;     they just serve as
  barriers.
- The goal is to have every    non-grey       tile covered by    a type of color.
- 2 by 2 non-grey squares of    the       same color    are    illegal.
- In future levels, there will be multiple numbers of the same color. Their groups must never intersect or be orthogonally adjacent to each other. There will be colored lines in certain places.
- The same-color group may not cross through the           colored
  lines, although they must border the line.

**New** :- To make this tough, some tiles having an intersection of 2 colours are not fully coloured. Your job is to colour them as well along with the others.

Here is the Real Puzzle, can you solve it? (This is going to be real tough)

[image]

**Bonus** :- Is the solution unique? If not, how many solutions can you find?

Comment: You haven't checked for uniqueness? [grid-deduction] puzzles should be unique - otherwise, you *can't* use pure logical deduction to get to the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regrettably there are a lot of solutions, e.g.

> [image]
>  Slight variations yield even many more, e.g. in picture 6 green could also have 'stolen' 8,11,12, or 18 i.s.o. 19 (starting from the congiguration above it)

Comment: Hmm, I actually didn't go and check for uniqueness you know (it takes a lot of work), but the idea is the same, there is definitely something that does not change in the solutions, the way you find them.

Comment: @Anonymous Checking for uniqueness [should be part of *how you construct the puzzle*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/97743/11876). If you solve the puzzle with pure logical deduction (no guessing, or writing down anything you are not 100% sure of), that automatically ensures uniqueness. And if you don't, then your solvers won't be able to either! If your puzzle is [edit: *not*] unique, it is literally impossible to use pure deduction to get to the solution.

Comment: ^ I think @Deusovi meant *If your puzzle is **not** unique* - and I echo his remarks. By their very definition a grid-*deduction* puzzle must be fully **deducible**. Otherwise it's just a 'grid puzzle', and in my experience a puzzle like that is nowhere near as satisfying for the solver as one where they manage to conquer and find that *one specific unique solution*. I strongly recommend you read Deusovi's linked post in the comment above - it is one of the best guides to creating a grid-deduction puzzle that you will find for free. Take the feedback, learn, practise, then blow us away! :)