# Tapa-Nurikolor (Level 6)

Tags: grid-deduction

Previous level: [Massive NuriKolor (Level 5) (Red-Fury)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102820/massive-nurikolor-level-5-red-fury) 
Next level: [Nurikolor (Level 7)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/nurikolor-level-7)

We now have Tapa involved in the Nurikolor puzzle, and this is the 6th one (if you include a spinoff.)

- There are colored numbers on the grid, which indicate the number of tiles the group of its color holds.
- There are tiles with 1 color, which indicate the color of the tile.
- There are tiles with 2 or more colors, which indicate intersections of colors. All intersections are shown, and these are the only intersections.
- Grey tiles are not part of any group; they just serve as barriers.
- The goal is to have every non-grey tile covered by a type of color.
- 2 by 2 non-grey squares of the same color are illegal.
- In future levels, there will be multiple numbers of the same color. Their groups must never intersect or be orthogonally adjacent to each other.
- There will be colored lines in certain places. The same-color group may not cross through the colored lines, although they must border the line.
- There may be intersections that aren't fully colored. It is also your job to color it.
- **NEW:** There are now "X"s on the board. This means the colored group cannot go into a "X" of the same color.
- **SPECIAL:** Tapa rules can also apply here, and all clues are on the gray squares.

Rules of Tapa: 
*Color black cells to create a single connected wall. Numbers in a cell indicate the length of consecutive shaded blocks of the same color in the neighboring cells. If there is more than one number in a cell, then there must be at least one different-colored cell between the colored cell groups. The shaded cells cannot form a 2×2 square anywhere in the grid.*

[image]

Colorblind version:

```
--- --- --- --- --- --- -p- --- --- ---
--- xxx --- --- p16 --- -?? --- xxx ---
--- --- --- xxx --- --- --- --- --- ---
-p- -?? --- --- --- xxx --- xxx --- k13
--- --- --- xxx --- -g- --- -c- --- y17
b12 --- --- --- -g7 --- xxx -yc --- -y-
--- --- xxx --- xxx --- -c8 --- -?c ---
--- --- -o- --- -r7 --- xxx --- -y- ---
-r6 xxx -?? -?? -rx --- -o- o11 xxx ---
--- --- -y- --- --- -?? --- -?? --- ---

R2C2 b8
R2C9 k6p2
R3C4 b2k1p5
R4C6 p5c1g2
R4C8 p5c3
R5C4 p3g5
R6C7 g1c5y1r2
R7C3 r2g3r1o2
R7C5 g3r5
R8C7 r2c2o4
R9C2 r3o3r1y2
R9C9 o3y6

r = red, o = orange, y = yellow, g = green, c = cyan, b = blue, p = purple, k = pink, xxx = gray, ?? = unknown
```

Comment: How does the Tapa rule work?

Comment: Will clarify :3

Comment: I think I probably got the meaning, that is like the number of tiles surrounding the grey square like in a minesweeper.

Comment: ...yes. That's kind of how it works. Not sure though...

Comment: You're not sure how your own puzzle works?

Comment: No, it's not like that... I'm not completely sure about the Tapa rules for this puzzle...!

Comment: Wait, what do you mean then? If you're not sure that the rules are accurate to Tapa, you can just write the rules in a way that is accurate instead, no?

Comment: ...just stop. I get it now. This is accurate.

Comment: @Player1456 I edited the puzzle a bit, I think it was unsolvable before.

Comment: Wait... I just noticed that somehow one of 6 puzzles in the series, which is puzzle 5, is written by Anonymous instead of Player1456... Now I'm confused...

Comment: I made it hence it is in my name, is there a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step-by-step logical path until puzzle break

> [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  [image]
>  Tapa deductions get us up to here.
>  [image]
>  Pink region fills to become size 13
>  [image]
>  Yellow region continues like this (currently size 14)
>  [image]
>  Orange escapes like this
>  [image]
>  Then red and yellow (yellow size 16)
>  [image]
>  Let's do the red 6 now
>  [image]
>  And the blue 12
>  [image]
>  Fill the last tapa
>  [image]
>  Fill out orange
>  [image]
>  This is the last image

There are a couple of ambiguities and errors at this point.

1. Purple region is currently size 12. It can extend to 14 with filling one intersection, and 16 with both intersections. This could be fixed if purple was 16.
2. Yellow could connect either way. Either way the last square is unaccounted for in terms of color. This could be fixed if, say, the light blue 7 region was an 8.

Comment: I don't remembering making the cyan 8 a 7... will be fixed. Also fixing purple 16 problems.

Comment: ...wait. I get the feeling that somehow things went wrong with an edit. Will fix, sorry...

Comment: Eh, closest answer. I like it. Just needs a little editing...