# Nurikolor (Level 8)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Previous Level: [Nurikolor (Level 7)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/nurikolor-level-7) 
Next Level: [Nurikolor (Level 9)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105655/nurikolor-level-9)

It's been 9 days since the last puzzle. We will start Level 8 right now, with new features.

- There are colored numbers on the grid, which indicate the number of
  tiles the group of its color holds.
- There are tiles with 1 color, which indicate the color of the tile.
- There are tiles with 2 or more colors, which indicate intersections of colors. All intersections are shown, and these are the only intersections.
- Grey tiles are not part of any group; they just serve as barriers.
- The goal is to have every non-grey tile covered by a type of color.
- 2 by 2 non-grey squares of the same color are illegal.
- There will be multiple numbers of the same color. Their groups must never intersect or be orthogonally adjacent to each other.
- There will be colored lines in certain places. The same-color group may not cross through the colored lines, although they must border the line.
- There may be intersections that aren't fully colored. It is also your job to color it.
- There are some tiles with two colours which are separated by a horizontal line drawn between them. This means that the tile is fully coloured by either of those 2 colours (you have to find which color it is colored with), not by any other colour.
- **NEW:** Bridges. If two squares are connected by a bridge, they are the same color and part of the same group. Bridges can connect to each other to make longer bridges. Colors passing through bridges do not count for the total color count.
- **NEW:** You cannot have a square be the same color as the color of the square(s) it goes over via a bridge (i.e. if B2 is blue, then B1-B3 cannot be blue if they're connected by a bridge.)

[image: Puzzle 8]

Colorblind version:

```
M11 -L- --- XXX -C- -R- --- --- -C- C12
--- -C? --- --- --- ??? --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- XXX --- -R- -C- --- --- ---
-Ml -L- --- XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX --- XXX
--- --- -L- XXX -L9 R13 XXX --- -Yu ---
--- --- --- XXX -B7 Y11 XXX -Y- --- ---
XXX --- XXX XXX XXX XXX XXX --- --- ---
-O- --- --- --- -B- --- XXX -P- --- -??
--- --- --- -B- --- -P- --- --- --- -P-
O10 -M? --- --- --- --- XXX --- --- P11

Chess notation, from top
H2 LR
B3 LR
C3 UD
F4 UD
D5 LR
H6 LR
J6 LD
A7 UD
E7 UD
A8 UD
D9 LR
F9 LR
G10 LR

R - Red, O = Orange, Y = yellow, L = Lime Green, C = Cyan, B = Blue, P = Purple, M = Pink (Magenta), XXX = Gray.
Lowercase letters indicate line direction in the grid.
u = up, d = down, l = left, r = right.
```

Comment: The length of the rules is getting larger... it'll only be a matter of time before you'll want a TL;DR part. ;)

Comment: What is the meaning of the narrow shaded sections, e.g. the magenta in R4C1?

Comment: @JeremyDover I think it's from the rule "There will be colored lines in certain places...".

Comment: Those are the revamped lines. Remember the lines from before? Yeah, I changed that to this.

Comment: At least the puzzle's got a unique solution this time. But the ruleset still looks uninteresting for a [tag:grid-deduction], unless you introduce same-colored numbers ASAP.

Comment: You will see them again in time. Maybe in the 11th, 12th, or 13th, not sure.

Comment: Edit: I lied. It's going to be in the 9th.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image]

Reasoning:

> Start with the yellow area: R5C9 has to be yellow because of the line, and then R5C8 is forced. The background color in R6C10 is yellow, since the only access to that square, except the two squares linked by the bridge, passes through yellow. We then increase yellow as far as we need to...its size blocks the intersection in R8C10 from all colors except yellow and purple, so those are the two colors there. This also forces the bridge to be purple. Easy deductions continue to:
>
>  [image]

The lower middle bridges:

> The color using these bridges cannot be either blue or purple. Magenta can reach, but using the bridge would force it to be at least 13 squares. So the bridge must be orange, the only other color that can reach them. At left, the bridge with the orange background can only be reached by magenta (red and cyan are blocked, green needs to many squares to get to R1C2). Continuing easy deductions yield:
>
>  [image]

Finishing up:

> R2C1 is magenta to get out of the corner. R3C1 has to be magenta, for if not the three squares R3C1, R4C2, and R3C3 would block magenta from getting to the bottom. Then we have R5C1 magenta too. Now move to cyan. There is only one way through from upper right to upper left, which must be cyan. Simple deductions from this path yields all 12 cyan squares. The rest of the upper right must be red. Finally, R1C3 is green, as is R1C2 down to R5C2. Then we need one more magenta and green square each, finishing the grid.