# Nurikolor (Level 9)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Previous Level: [Nurikolor (Level 8)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/104057/nurikolor-level-8)

It's been almost two months since I've last done this. Don't worry, I'm not dead, I was just working on this. 
**RULES:**

- There are colored numbers on the grid, which indicate the number of
  tiles the group of its color holds.
- There are tiles with 1 color, which indicate the color of the tile.
- There are tiles with 2 or more colors, which indicate intersections of colors. All intersections are shown, and these are the only intersections.
- Grey tiles are not part of any group; they just serve as barriers.
- The goal is to have every non-grey tile covered by a type of color.
- 2 by 2 non-grey squares of the same color are illegal.
- There will be multiple numbers of the same color. Their groups must never intersect or be orthogonally adjacent to each other.
- There will be colored lines in certain places. The same-color group may not cross through the colored lines, although they must border the line.
- There may be intersections that aren't fully colored. It is also your job to color it.
- There are some tiles with two colours which are separated by a horizontal line drawn between them. This means that the tile is fully coloured by either of those 2 colours (you have to find which color it is colored with), not by any other colour.
- Bridges. If two squares are connected by a bridge, they are the same color and part of the same group. Bridges can connect to each other to make longer bridges. Colors passing through bridges do not count for the total color count.
- You cannot have a square be the same color as the color of the square(s) it goes over via a bridge (i.e. if B2 is blue, then B1-B3 cannot be blue if they're connected by a bridge.)

[image: Puzzle 9]

Colorblind Version (Colors only:)

```
XX???X?????X
?X???X??YXXX
?XX??XG??X??
???XRY??XGOG
????B?XO????
???RXY??GXXX
XXX?*?GX????
????RX???G??
???X?B??X???
??X?*BX+?XX?
XXXB??X???X?
X?????X???XX
Line Colors, Passed: (+): R7C7G
Split Colors (*): R7C5R?, R10C5RB
R = Red, O = Orange, Y = Yellow, G = Green, B = Blue, X = Gray
```

Oh, and don't mind the black and white fonts of the blue regions. I just forgot to change these.

Comment: Are the parts in spoilers intended to be hints towards the solution? If they're just parts of the puzzle proper then they should be un-spoilered

Comment: They're not part of the puzzle at all, just notes.

Comment: If they're not part of the puzzle, don't include them. Spoilers are *not* for including off-topic comments. Spoilers in questions should be used very rarely: the only common use case for them is hints, which these are definitely not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:

> The yellow region is the only one that can block the two reds from colliding. The red is the only one that can reach R8C1.
>   [image]
>  The entire top left section is now isolated, and can be solved as its own puzzle.
>  [image]

Now some connectivity logic: a cell under a bridge with a wall on one side can only extend one way.

> Blue is the only one that can reach the bottom middle area.
>  [image]
>  Blue cannot reach both the bottom middle and the region left of the red 14, so yellow has to be the color to mix with red. There's only one way to connect it to the bridge in the top right and use only 17 cells.
>  [image]

And more "only one color can reach this", over and over, finishes off the puzzle.

> [image]

Comment: That was quick :) Good job!

Comment: @Player1456 Most of the puzzle was pretty easy because only one or two colors could even reach most of the squares. I'd try to make puzzles where more colors can access any specific square at the start. (The bridges are very constraining, because they act as "walls" in two directions -- here, this split the puzzle into multiple independent pieces pretty easily, and the independent pieces were mostly trivial to solve once you noticed that only two colors could be in them.)

Comment: Yeah... I'm not very good at making these.